# printWarnings command doesn't show deprecation warnings

Tags: scala, sbt

Sbt tells me my project compiled with one deprecation warning but using the `printWarnings` command shows me nothing.

```
> compile
[info] Updating {file:...}root...
[info] Resolving jline#jline;2.12 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Compiling 8 Scala sources to /.../...
[warn] there was one deprecation warning; re-run with -deprecation for details
[warn] one warning found
[success] Total time: 7 s, completed Dec 12, 2014 11:32:13 AM
> printWarnings
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Dec 12, 2014 11:33:13 AM
```

Is it the correct way to do?

Edit: I'm using sbt 0.13.7.

Answer (score 2):

You can add compiler options inside your build.sbt file, so to add the deprecation option you can do this:

```
scalacOptions += "-deprecation"
```

Then you can do a `reload`, `clean`, and `compile` inside sbt and you should see the full warning